# displaying sqlite table in listview fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

im developing an app with listview selected item will go to next activity and implement swipe to view the next item , i got a tutorial and it works fine using fragment and parcel class but i dont know how to display the sqlite data and populate it in listview

//here is my code in dbcontroller

```
package com.example.ansiuser.swipe;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.id.list;

public class DBController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    public final String TABLE_NAME = "Countsheet";

    public DBController(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext, "Count.db", null, 1);  // creating DATABASE
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Countsheet ( Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , Category TEXT,Code TEXT,Description TEXT, Unit TEXT, Quantity TEXT)";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }


    public final class FeedReaderContract {
        // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
        // make the constructor private.
        private FeedReaderContract() {
        }

        /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
        public class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
            public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Countsheet";

            public static final String Col_1 = "Id";
            public static final String Col_2 = "Category";
            public static final String Col_3 = "Code";
            public static final String Col_4 = "Description";
            public static final String Col_5 = "Unit";
            public static final String Col_6 = "Quantity";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old,
                          int current_version) {
        String query;
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Countsheet";
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
    }


}
```

//here is main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    Button btnimport;
    PagerFragment pagerFragment;
    public static final int requestcode = 1;
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnimport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupload);





        final ArrayList<PageData> data = new ArrayList<PageData>();
        data.add(new PageData(1, "Picture13432423423423432423432","Category","Code","Description","Unit","Quantity"));
        data.add(new PageData(2, "Picture2","Category","Code","Description","Unit","Quantity"));
        data.add(new PageData(3, "Picture3","Category","Code","Description","Unit","Quantity"));
        data.add(new PageData(4, "Picture4","Category","Code","Description","Unit","Quantity"));
        data.add(new PageData(5, "Picture5","Category","Code","Description","Unit","Quantity"));
        data.add(new PageData(6, "Picture6","Category","Code","Description","Unit","Quantity"));
        data.add(new PageData(7, "Picture7","Category","Code","Description","Unit","Quantity"));
        data.add(new PageData(8, "Picture8","Category","Code","Description","Unit","Quantity"));
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        ListViewAdapter lva = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.item_list, data);
        lv.setAdapter(lva);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {




            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //peace of code that create launch new fragment with swipe view inside
                PagerFragment pagerFragment = new PagerFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("CURRENT_POSITION", position);
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("DATA_LIST", data);
                pagerFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container, pagerFragment, "swipe_view_fragment").commit();

            }
        });
        btnimport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertdialog.setTitle("Confirm Import...");
                alertdialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Import Data?");
                alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//                        clearApplicationData();
                        Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        fileintent.setType("gagt/sdf");
                        try {
                            startActivityForResult(fileintent, requestcode);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
//                    lbl.setText("No activity can handle picking a file. Showing alternatives.");
                        }


                    }
                });

                alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Import Canceled" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }
                });
                alertdialog.show();

            }
        });


    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (data == null)
            return;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case requestcode:
                String filepath = data.getData().getPath();
                controller = new DBController(getApplicationContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db = controller.getWritableDatabase();
                String tableName = "Countsheet";
                db.execSQL("delete from " + tableName);
                try {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            FileReader file = new FileReader(filepath);
                            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
                            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                            String line = "";
                            db.beginTransaction();

                            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                                String[] str = line.split(",", 5);  // defining 5 columns with null or blank field //values acceptance
                                //Id, category,code,Description,Unit,Quantity
                                String company = str[0].toString();
                                String Name = str[1].toString();
                                String Price = str[2].toString();
                                String units = str[3].toString();
                                String quants = str[4].toString();


                                contentValues.put("Category", company);
                                contentValues.put("Code", Name);
                                contentValues.put("Description", Price);
                                contentValues.put("Unit", units);
                                contentValues.put("Quantity", quants);
                                db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
//                                lbl.setText("Successfully Updated Database.");
                            }
                            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                            db.endTransaction();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            if (db.inTransaction())
                                db.endTransaction();
                            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                            d.setTitle(e.getMessage().toString() + "first");
                            d.show();
                            // db.endTransaction();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (db.inTransaction())
                            db.endTransaction();
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Only CSV files allowed");
                        d.show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    if (db.inTransaction())
                        db.endTransaction();

                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle(ex.getMessage().toString() + "second");
                    d.show();
                    // db.endTransaction();
                }

        }



            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"data Imported",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



}
```

// here is parcel class

```
package com.example.ansiuser.swipe;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Created by ansiuser on 11/01/2017.
 */

public class PageData implements Parcelable{
    private int picture;
    private String title ;
    private String Category ;
    private String Code ;
    private String Description ;
    private String Unit ;
    private String Quantity ;

    public PageData(){
    }

    public PageData(Parcel in){
        picture = in.readInt();
        title = in.readString();
        Category = in.readString();
        Code = in.readString();
        Description = in.readString();
        Unit = in.readString();
        Quantity = in.readString();
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(picture);
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(Category);
        dest.writeString(Code);
        dest.writeString(Description);
        dest.writeString(Unit);
        dest.writeString(Quantity);
    }

    public PageData(int picture, String title , String cat,String code,String desk, String unit, String quan){
        this.picture = picture;
        this.title = title;
        this.Category = cat;
        this.Code = code;
        this.Description = desk;
        this.Unit = unit;
        this.Quantity = quan;

    }

    public int getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return Code;
    }
    public String getDesk() {
        return Description;
    }
    public String getUnit() {
        return Unit;
    }
    public String getQuantity() {
        return Quantity;
    }

    public static final Creator<PageData> CREATOR = new Creator<PageData>() {
        @Override
        public PageData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new PageData(in);
        }

        @Override
        public PageData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PageData[size];
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: you can use a cursor loader. search for tutorials and you will find many on the net

Comment: can you give me good links or example sir ? thankss!

Comment: @Raghunandan icant use it because it requires me list should be parcelable

Comment: No need. Since data is in database you can access info in another activity directly

Comment: how about the parcelable class? i will disregard it?

Comment: Data is in database right? You require parcelable ( for model class) if you want to send data via intent. If your data is in database you could get the data in another activity also which does not require all those parcelable implementation. using cursor loader is efficient.

Comment: ok ill look into it because im implementing swipe to see the next item after clicking listview thank ill inform you right away sir THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR PAYING ATTENTION TO BEGINNERS LIKE ME :)

Comment: @Raghunandan i used cursor loader but then i cant implement fragment activity which i need to swipe to go to next item after clicking listview